# I cant click on a link in selenium using firefox browser

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, automation

I want to click on the Search link mentioned in the below HTML, have highlighted it as well; but selenium is not recognising it, The last line of the code

below(**Search**).

DesktopActivity

**Search**

Comment: Could you put the code you are using. The html and the selenium?

Comment: Hi J. following is the code please review;

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="if (isCtrlOrShiftDown ()) return (false);">Search</a> I want to pick the Search link.

Comment: To click on this button with a : `driver.findelement(by.xpath(".//a[text()='Search']")).click()` but maybe with more code we can help you more.

Comment: Hi J. I cant enter more than 15 characters of comment.

Comment: <li class="currentDepth1" id="dhtmlgoodies_listItem1" style="float: left;"><a href="#" onclick="if (isCtrlOrShiftDown ()) return (false);">Activity</a><img src="/Jasper/images/smallHeaderDivider.PNG" alt="divider" class="igMenuImgDivider"></li><li class="currentDepth1" id="dhtmlgoodies_listItem6" style="float: left;"><a href="#" onclick="if (isCtrlOrShiftDown ()) return (false);">Search</a>

Comment: You can edit your question :) and add more information on it.

Comment: Please update your question with code  example so we can help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this out by myself, problem was with the Firefox driver (GekoDriver) i have downgraded it and executed the script it went well. Tried several times no issue still. Hence closing this question and thanks for the help